# Como exibir mensagem de "carregando" enquanto a WebView está carregando?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Preciso apresentar uma mensagem em tela enquanto o componente WebView não carregou por completo, mas não sei como detectar se ela já terminou de carregar o conteúdo. Aqui está o meu código:

```
return (    
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <WebView 
      style={styles.webview}
      setSupportMultipleWindows={false}
      ref={this.WEBVIEW_REF}
      javaScriptEnabled={true}
      allowsFullscreenVideo={true}
      onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange}
      source={{ uri: 'https://pei.educacao.mg.gov.br/login' }}  />
  </View>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Acho que uma boa solução aqui seria usar o compontente 
[ActivityIndicator](https://reactnative.dev/docs/activityindicator)

É um componente nativo que pode ser customizado, vai ser exibido no lugar do componente enquanto ele é carregador, e pode exibir ele baseado no `state` do seu componente, algo assim:

```
const App = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <WebView
          style={styles.webview}
          setSupportMultipleWindows={false}
          ref={this.WEBVIEW_REF}
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
          allowsFullscreenVideo={true}
          onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange}
          source={{ uri: 'https://pei.educacao.mg.gov.br/login' }}
          onLoadStart={() => setVisible(true)}
          onLoad={() => setVisible(false)}
        />
        {visible ? <ActivityIndicatorElement size="large" /> : null}
      </View>
  );
};
```

Aqui foi usado o `visible` e `setVisiblie` para controlar a visibilidade do `WebView` e mudar isso com `onLoadStart` e `onLoad`

Tenho um componente assim, foi baseado nesse código: [react-native-show-progress-bar-while-loading-webview](https://snack.expo.io/embedded/@aboutreact/react-native-show-progress-bar-while-loading-webview?preview=true&platform=ios&iframeId=hu1asvf5eu&theme=dark)

Comment: A resposta está correta, apenas ressalto aqui para ter atenção quando utilizar arrow functions no render. Conforme mencionado na [documentação](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#arrow-function-in-render): "Ao usar uma arrow function no render, uma nova função é criada cada vez que o componente é renderizado, que pode quebrar otimizações com base em comparação de identidade `on strict`." Eu prefiro evitar e faço uso de uma regra do ESLint para me alertar isso: [react/jsx-no-bind](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md)